# ggplot2 - label x axis with value from different column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know if there is a way to replace the label in the x-axis with the value from a different column. Suppose I have this data frame.

```
Chromosome  Value  Region
chr1        2      centromere
chr1        2.1    telomere
chr2        2.2    centromere
chr2        1.9    telomere
chr3        2      centromere
chr3        2      telomere
```

I would like to plot "Region" (x-axis) against "Value" (y-axis), adjust the data point shape according to "Region", but change the x-axis label according to "Chromosome". I tried to plot "Chromosome" against "Value" but the data points become stacked as shown below.

[image]

Plotting "Region" against "Value" would create a correct plot but the x-axis label would not be very informative. I want the data points to be to not stack like the figure above. Any tips or help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please include a minimal dataset in order to test and verify possible solutions?  see [mre], you could try adding your data with `dput("your_dataframe")` if the data frame is not too large. Best to generate a subset with the absolute minimal data which illustrates your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` to `geom_point`:

```r
d <- read.table(text = "Chromosome  Value  Region
chr1        2      centromere
chr1        2.1    telomere
chr2        2.2    centromere
chr2        1.9    telomere
chr3        2      centromere
chr3        2      telomere", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(Chromosome, Value, shape = Region, color = Chromosome)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: width = 0.9 is a bit random;) , and I'd probably add group = Region just to make sure it does dodge on the correct group...  +1